# AWS SQS FIFO event messageAttributes example?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, aws-sqs-fifo

For AWS SQS FIFO queues, on [AWS official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#sample-fifo-queues-message-event), I could not find any clear examples for the format of the `messageAttributes` object (which is a sub-object within the `event` object, aka the queue message event object).

Can anyone provide an example of the full SQS FIFO queue message event object? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example of SQS FIFO event object (in particular, the `messsageAttributes` object):

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "11d6ee51-4cc7-4302-9e22-7cd8afdaadf5",
            "receiptHandle": "AQEBBX8nesZEXmkhsmZeyIE8iQAMig7qw...",
            "body": "Test message.",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "1",
                "SentTimestamp": "1573251510774",
                "SequenceNumber": "18849496460467696128",
                "MessageGroupId": "1",
                "SenderId": "AIDAIO23YVJENQZJOL4VO",
                "MessageDeduplicationId": "1",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1573251510774"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {
                'myKey': {
                    'stringValue': 'myStringValue', 
                    'stringListValues': [], 
                    'binaryListValues': [], 
                    'dataType': 'String'
                }
            },
            "md5OfBody": "e4e68fb7bd0e697a0ae8f1bb342846b3",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-east-2:123456789012:fifo.fifo",
            "awsRegion": "us-east-2"
        }
    ]
}
```

This Q&A post is to provide an example output of the `event` object, to supplement the official documentation. I will also be making a pull request about this in due time.